# textit{} and textbf{} are not working and there are multiple errors which I don't know how to resolve

Tags: errors, luatex, tex-core, text-manipulation

This is the code,

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=9in, paperheight=14in]{geometry}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{empheq}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[%
ItalicFont=NewCM10-Italic.otf%
BoldFont=NewCM10-Bold.otf,%
BoldItalicFont=NewCM10-BoldItalic.otf,%
SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}]{NewCM10-Regular.otf}

\setsansfont[%
ItalicFont=NewCMSans10-Oblique.otf,%
BoldFont=NewCMSans10-Bold.otf,%
BoldItalicFont=NewCMSans10-BoldOblique.otf,%
SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}]{NewCMSans10-Regular.otf}

\setmonofont[ItalicFont=NewCMMono10-Italic.otf,%
BoldFont=NewCMMono10-Bold.otf,%
BoldItalicFont=NewCMMono10-BoldOblique.otf,%
SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}]{NewCMMono10-Regular.otf}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

Stay back, I'm \textit{going} to do some \textbf{science}.

\end{document}
```

---

Error

```
~/.config/nvim/test5.tex      0:0      W Package lualatex-math Warning: I've expected \MT_cramped_internal: Nn to have the meaning macro:#1#2-->\setbox \z@ \hbox {$\m@th #1\kern} -\nulldelimiterspace \radical \z@ {#2}$}\ifx .... "some long error, it's very long to type and I can't copy it. tell me if its needed."

~/.config/nvim/test5.tex      23:0     E Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.

~/.config/nvim/test5.tex      23:0     E Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.

~/.config/nvim/test5.tex      23:0     E Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.

~/.config/nvim/test5.tex      23:0     E Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.

~/.config/nvim/test5.tex      0:0      W Latex Font Warning: Font shape 'TU/NewCM10-Regular.otf(0)/m/it' undefined using 'TU/NewCM10-Regular.otf(0)/m/n' instead on input line 40.
```

Comment: You have to use ` for code blocks, not '

Comment: what? sorry I didn't understand.

Comment: You used `'''` in your question, that won't show your code in a code block. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/690516/revisions for the difference

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing `,` after `ItalicFont=NewCM10-Italic.otf`:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=9in, paperheight=14in]{geometry}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{empheq}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[%
ItalicFont=NewCM10-Italic.otf,%
BoldFont=NewCM10-Bold.otf,%
BoldItalicFont=NewCM10-BoldItalic.otf,%
SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}
]{NewCM10-Regular.otf}
%
\setsansfont[%
ItalicFont=NewCMSans10-Oblique.otf,%
BoldFont=NewCMSans10-Bold.otf,%
BoldItalicFont=NewCMSans10-BoldOblique.otf,%
SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}]{NewCMSans10-Regular.otf}

\setmonofont[ItalicFont=NewCMMono10-Italic.otf,%
BoldFont=NewCMMono10-Bold.otf,%
BoldItalicFont=NewCMMono10-BoldOblique.otf,%
SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}]{NewCMMono10-Regular.otf}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

Stay back, I'm \textit{going} to do some \textbf{science}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my god, it solved all the problems. Thank You. There is still the first error but as long it is working it's good.

Comment: @Nick You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Always look at the first error message, in your case

```
! Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \???
                 ! LaTeX Error: Misplaced '=' in key-value input on line 31
l.31
```

which is quite clear: there's a missing comma in a line preceding line 31. And don't look at the scanty resumé presented by Vim: look in the log file.

There are a few other errors in you code. Don't load `amssymb` together with `unicode-math`, you only make TeX do useless work (or get errors if the former package is loaded after the latter).

You can save keystrokes, also gaining in clarity, if you use `fontspec` features when defining fonts.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=9in, paperheight=14in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
%\usepackage{amssymb} % not with unicode-math
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\setmainfont{NewCM10}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,% <--- was missing
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle},
]

\setsansfont{NewCMSans10}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Oblique,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldOblique,
  SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle},
]

\setmonofont{NewCMMono10}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldOblique,
  SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle},
]

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

Stay back, I'm \textit{going} to do some \textbf{science}.

\texttt{Stay back, I'm \textit{going} to do some \textbf{science}.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `%` after commas in key-value options is not needed; take the habit of always adding a trailing comma in that context.